# Parse object to a dynamically supplied type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, generics

I have following generic method in C# that parses client data from an ASP.NET web forms application into some defined type:

```
public static T ParseClientRequest <T> (object data) 
{
    var t = (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>) data;
    T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    foreach(var pair in t) {
        FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField(pair.Key);
        field.SetValue(obj, pair.Value);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I have two questions about it:

1. Is there any efficient way(using LINQ or other) of doing it without using loop? Or is it efficient enough?
2. The code throws exception if one of the type's field is of type other than string. How the object type can be parsed to a dynamically supplied type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Efficiency is relative. Hard to answer. If it is *good enough* for you, then no problem

2- You can fix your code by using `Convert.ChangeType`

```
public static T ParseClientRequest<T>(object data)
{
    var t = (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>)data;
    T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    foreach (var pair in t)
    {
        FieldInfo field = obj.GetType().GetField(pair.Key);
        field.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(pair.Value, field.FieldType)); //See this line
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eser. It worked like a charm. :) Not necessary but can you tell me how can we modify this code so that it can convert `int` to `enum` type if any `enum` type field is detected? Currently it throws `InvalidCastException`. But it's ok if it cannot be done inside this method. I will convert it during processing after this method's call. But if possible in this method then it will be great. :)

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva You will need an `if` to check whether the type is enum. You can use now `Enum.Parse`.

Comment: Yeah I tried this `if (field.GetType().IsEnum)
                    field.SetValue(obj, Enum.Parse(field.GetType(), pair.Value.ToString()));` but its not working. The condition is not getting true.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva it should be `field.FieldType`

Comment: thanks it worked and I edited your code so that it can allow conversion of `enum` and `object` types. Making it a more generic method. :)